# tool for switching NIC status on off on windows

Tags: windows, nic

is there a tool that can turn on/off (enable, disable) an NIC interface on windows OS?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Crack open a cmd.exe window and do the following:

netsh interface set interface "Name of Interface" ENABLE

OR

netsh interface set interface "Name of Interface" DISABLE

Comment: it says "An interface with this name is not registered with the router"?

Comment: maruti: you must replace "Name of Interface" with the actual interface name as displayed under Network Connections. This is usually "Local Area Connection" for the first interface, "Local Area Connection 2" for the second and "Wireless Network Connection" for WLAN.

Answer (score 2):

found this MS utility that can enable, disable, restart and query individual devices or groups of devices

DEVCON for W2k3 and XP
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q311272&ID=KB;EN-US;Q311272